# The name and quantity of products on the category page are not displayed

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

I have a problem. I have code for outputting the category name and the number of products on the category pages, but after updating the woocommerce from version 3.2.6 to 3.3.5 the name ceased to be displayed

Here is the code

```
function add_product_count_view() {
global $post;
$terms = get_term_by( $post->ID, 'product_cat');
foreach( $terms as $term ) {
    if(is_tax('product_cat', $term->name)) {
        echo '<h3 class="woo-category-name">'
            . $term->name
            .'<span class="woo-category-count">'
            . '('
            . $term->count
            . ')'
            .'<span/>'
            . '</h3>';
    }
  }
}
```

There is also such an error: Warning: Invalid argument supplied for forach () in /home/d/devenup/evok.dvnup.com/public_html/wp-content/themes/evok/functions.php on line 18

But it was and before the update

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Product is simple post for wordpress so you can use it same as normal post.Please try following code and modify as requirement.

```
global $post;

    $terms = get_the_terms( $post->ID, 'product_cat' );
if(is_array($terms)){
    foreach ($terms as $term) {
        $product_cat = $term->name;
        break;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the support.
The name has been displayed but the error has not disappeared

Comment: You need to put check

Comment: Thanks for the answer, your answer is correct, I was a little mistaken =)